# Uwp Combobox Binding Breaks on Source Change

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox, uwp

I'm having an issue in UWP using MVVM, where I have a `Combobox` with an `ItemsSource` bound to a collection of items in my ViewModel, and also in my VM is an item from that collection that `SelectedItem` is bound to.

I need to change both the items source and the selected item at will in my view model. The problem is, if the `SelectedItem` doesn't exist in the `ItemsSource` at any point in time, the binding for `SelectedItem` seems to break permanently.

Example:
Let's say I have a Comobox that is bound to my VM:

```
<ComoboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Now in my ViewModel, I have:

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; } // Pretend these properties call on OnPropertyChanged
public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

public void Initialize() {
    Items = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    SelectedItem = "B";
}

public void ChangeList() {
    // This breaks the binding that the Combobox has with SelectedItem
    Items = new List<string> { "E", "F", "G", "H" };

    // This does nothing on the XAML side as the binding is already broken by this poing
    SelectedItem = "H";
}
```

When initialized, the app will show "B" in the selected combo box. If in the code, say, I change it to "A", that will also reflect a change in the view. However, when I call `ChangeList()` the combo box will be set to blank and will ignore any changes I make in code behind.

Unfortunately in my case, setting `SelectedItem` to null before I update the source list does not fix my problem.

How would I go about changing the source and selected item in the VM?

Comment: Same problem happens in WPF.

Comment: Based on a couple of other answers in the sidebar, I think the only way to deal with this is to write a wrapper object that re-implements `SelectedItem` (and probably a couple of other properties).  This feels like a bug in the control where it's not using the correct means of updating the property value.  (I started down that road before figuring out that my issue was that empty string will break the binding when the list is cleared, but null string will not.)

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `Items` to a new collection, the `ComboBox` should auto-reset the `SelectedItem` for you. You will need to receive this change and respond with a `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Try changing your binding to two-way:

```
<ComoboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: I do agree that it should work like that. I have observed that the `SelectedItem` gets set to `null` when I set the binding mode to `TwoWay`, but after that the binding seems to remain broken. Changing the item in the data model no longer triggers a `get` on the combobox and nothing gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

User an ObservableCollection instead of a List

public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _Items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "A","B", "C"};
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == _Items)
            { return; }
            _Items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }
```

Ok, I'm not sure what your code looks like but if you are replacing the ItemsSource of your ComboBox then you can do this:

Items.Clear();

Items = new ObservableCollection{ "D","E", "F"};

SelectedItem =Items.FirstOrDefault ( c => c == "D");

You will have to do your own error checking to see if "D" exists in the collection by doing Items.Any( c => c == "D");  This will return a true or false.  If it returns true then go ahead and set your selecteditem:
SelectedItem =Items.FirstOrDefault ( c => c == "D");

Now keep in mind "D" can be any string.
string searchString = "";

so now you can fill the Lambda statement like this:
SelectedItem =Items.FirstOrDefault ( c => c == searchString);

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I'm not adding/removing the items in the source, I'm replacing it with a new list. This causes the current `SelectedItem` to no longer exist in the list, and that is what I'm thinking breaks the binding

Comment: Ok, not sure exactly what your code looks like but if your remove the ItemSource you will have to look for the item in your ObservableCollection.  So, what I would do is do this:

Comment: At least in WPF, it doesn't matter if the collection is an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately in UWP it does matter :/

Comment: I mean that in a negative sense: my experience with WPF is that changing to `ObservableCollection` doesn't make this behavior go away.